Read compressed CSVs with Polars in parallel
Let's say I have a list of .csv.xz files and I want to read them in parallel.
I know I can do this sequentially using a generator expression:
import glob
import lzma
import polars as pl

the_path = 'paths/to/my/*.csv.xz'
all_dfs = pl.concat(
    (pl.read_csv(lzma.open(i)) for i in sorted(glob(the_path))), 
    how='vertical')

But I am also aware of the possibility(?) of reading them in parallel: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/io/multiple/#reading-and-processing-in-parallel. Reading pl.scan_csv's method signature, it seems that this is only possible with Path or List[Path]. And given there doesn't seem to be any compression inference yet (contra pd.read_csv('file.csv.xz')) does this mean I am SOL with compressed CSVs?
Alternatively, is it otherwise possible to do the IO in parallel sans something like joblib or concurrent.futures?

I don't think there is anything as of yet, other than converting your data to parquet. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7287
